# How can/do I configure my Spring app to check a specific tag of configs with custom directory?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Suppose I have the following dir:

- root.properties
- dev-ci

  - common.properties
  - app_dir

    - app.properties
- prod
- stage
- test

test/stage/prod all follow dev-ci's dir/path structure.

How can I setup my bootstrap.yml file so that when I start my app, it'll load the following:

- root.properties
- dev-ci/common.properties
- dev-ci/app_dir/app.properties

Is there a way to set up my yml so that it takes some parameter from commandline? Or will I have to map out all the possible 'paths' then pass in some label/name?

Lastly, where does the tag name come into play?

Comment: Is there a reason that spring profiles could not used to handle this?

Comment: i did a bunch of changes, and it got worse than before; so i figured ask SO see if there's any examples etc.